# How can I connect .ejs files to .html file?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I want to connect my login.ejs file to index.html file. My directory looks like this:

```
UserService directory
   app.js
   views
   - login.ejs
   - signup.ejs
   - dashboard.ejs
Website
   - index.html
```

I searched on stackoverflow and worked with some solutions:

In index.html(For connecting login page with the index.html page):

```
<a class="nav-link btn btn-warning signup" href="./UserService/views/login.ejs">Login</a>
```

In app.js:

```
app.get('./views/login.ejs',function(req,res,next){
 res.render('login');
});
```

I incorportated the above solution and some other solutions mentioned in other posts. However, I am continuing to get my login.ejs file's *code* on the website.
Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To link the ejs pages to either html, php pages, you need to go to the app.js file and set the view engine correspondingly.

Inside app.js

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view engine','html');
app.set('view engine','php');
```

Don't forget to install these dependencies using `npm install html`
Finally use render function to render any type of frontend pages as shown:

```
router.get('/', forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('index.html')); 

#Incase of a .php file. 
router.get('/', forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('index.php'));
```

In the html/php source code, you can directly use the routes you created to link the pages.

```
<a class="nav-link btn btn-warning signup" href="/users/login">Login</a>
```

To illustrate the above statement, I am including the snippet of routes file which renders the login.ejs file:

In routes/users.js

```
router.get('/login', forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('login.ejs'));
```

Hope the solution helps. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Why make the route './views/login.ejs'  instead of just './views/login'  removing the extension is good practice
Apart from that
Your route is pointing to another location

```js
app.get('./views/login.ejs',function(req,res,next){
 res.render('login');
});
//which is this => 127.0.0.1:80/views/login.ejs
```

So change your code to

```
<a class="nav-link btn btn-warning signup" href="./views/login.ejs">Login</a>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this. But now, I cant access the page itself. It shows the error "File not found"
Earlier I was able to see my code on the webpage.